# Website Login, ASPX Login Page from app

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi I'm very new to Xcode, 
Im trying to use this tutorial to login to a website the website is ASPX it has a simple username and password field but no matter what i do i cannot get it to login

[Tutorial](http://dipinkrishna.com/blog/2013/12/ios-login-screen-tutorial-xcode-5-ios-7-storyboard-json/5/)

Any advice would be great thanks.

essentially i would like this code:

```
(IBAction)sigininClicked:(id)sender {
NSInteger success = 0;
@try {

    if([[self.txtUsername text] isEqualToString:@""] || [[self.txtPassword text] isEqualToString:@""] ) {

        [self alertStatus:@"Please enter Email and Password" :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];

    } else {
        NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",[self.txtUsername text],[self.txtPassword text]];
        NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);

        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dipinkrishna.com/jsonlogin.php"];

        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];

        //[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];

        NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
        NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
        NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

        NSLog(@"Response code: %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);

        if ([response statusCode] >= 200 && [response statusCode] < 300)
        {
            NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);

            NSError *error = nil;
            NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization
                                      JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                                      options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                      error:&error];

            success = [jsonData[@"success"] integerValue];
            NSLog(@"Success: %ld",(long)success);

            if(success == 1)
            {
                NSLog(@"Login SUCCESS");
            } else {

                NSString *error_msg = (NSString *) jsonData[@"error_message"];
                [self alertStatus:error_msg :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];
            }

        } else {
            //if (error) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            [self alertStatus:@"Connection Failed" :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];
        }
    }
}
@catch (NSException * e) {
    NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
    [self alertStatus:@"Sign in Failed." :@"Error!" :0];
}
if (success) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login_success" sender:self];
}
}

- (void) alertStatus:(NSString *)msg :(NSString *)title :(int) tag
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                    message:msg
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
alertView.tag = tag;
[alertView show];
}

- (IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender {
[self.view endEditing:YES];
}

-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
[textField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
}
```

@end

To login to this website [LOGIN LINK](https://www.creditexpert.co.uk/MCCLogin.aspx)

Comment: Explain your problem please, you won't get any help with such a broad question.

Comment: What has this to do with Xcode? Xcode is an IDE. You could write the code with vim and compile with xcodebuild.

Comment: What response do you get from the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to check the request in login page(web page). Have a look at it and see the login logic there. Check these: Does it use json too, does it use "Accept" as HTTPHeaderField for json data? Does it put the username and password in httpbody as this kind of format--> "username=%@&password=%@"? Does the password should get encrypted when sending request? Which url you should use?

Generally, you should change the request part in code to satisfy the specific api for login.